# How to use router links inside switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

Whats the correct way to use react router links inside switch components?
I have tried the following but I can't get this right.

I'm guessing I can not use links to route paths once they are wrapped with switch component.

```
 <Router>
  <Switch>
   <Route path="/">
      <Link to="/start">התחל</Link>
   </Route>
   <Route path="/start">
     test
   </Route>
  </Switch>
 </Router>
```

How can I route using link component wrapped inside switch component?

Comment: what is your usecase?

Comment: @PrateekThapa Trying to create interactive questions that will create screen transition according to answers

Comment: use the `exact` prop

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-flower-2p652

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your routes are matching with first route, you need to put `exact` as the prop to your first route.

```
 <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
            <Link to="/start">התחל</Link>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/start">
          <p>test</p>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```